# MaterializeCSS Change Option Color for Some Options

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I am using a select dropdown from [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/select.html). I want to create a class that will change the text color of some options. Is there a way to do that?

I saw that I can change the color in general by doing:

```
.dropdown-content li>a, .dropdown-content li>span {
    color: red;
}
```

but this will affect all dropdown colors to be red. Is there a way to specify a class that can alter the text color for only some options.

I was looking to have something like the following:

```
<option value='A'>A</option>
<option value='B' class='red'>B</option>
<option value='C'>C</option>
```

Comment: You are free to apply any custom classes or ids to your elements. That's what they're for: targeting elements so they can be styled without having to change markup later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the behaviour of materializecss' javascript components from the html, since they are rewritten (the `select` you see is not the original one you provided in the html, since that one is `hidden`)

To achieve what you have requested i have used a simple loop over the new "`option`" elements just after the initzialization. When it finds the one you want, it sets the class of the element to the materializecss' helper class `materialize-red-text`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
    changeColor();
});

function changeColor(){
  var options_elem = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content li>a, .dropdown-content li>span");
  
  //index==0 is the disabled option element
  options_elem.forEach(function(element, index){
    if(index == "2") element.classList.add("materialize-red-text"); //or you could use class "redtext"
  });
}
```

```css
.redtext {
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```